# Read data tags from URL and input into a JS Variable

Tags: javascript, html, forms, variables, uri

The general idea is to have a URL, index.html?variable01=response01&variable02=response02

and that will produce js varibles with the string before the equal sign as the variable name, and the string after it be it's value. I've tried this so far: *it hasnt worked*

```
var strings = window.location.search("?*") //filter the website URL itself

var varsets = strings.split('&') //split earch variable set, makes var=value

var varcommands = strings.search.append('var ') //add the string 'var to each of the sets, 
makes var var=value

for (x = 0, y < vars.length, x++) { 
 sections = vars.search.replace('=',' = ') //add spaces around the equals sign,
makes var var = value

function x() {  //define a function to process the value of sections as a command
  return sections
 }
 for (y = 0, y < sections.length, y++) { //cycle through and run each command string
  x()
}
```

Comment: search for a "queryString parser for js"

Comment: thank you, very helpful, Ill search it now